# How can I pass useParams to mapStateToProps in React with React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, reselect

In my application, I want to pass the parameter that I'm getting from `useParams()` to the `mapStateToProps` function which I'm using with the [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library.

I can hard code the value instead of passing this parameter and everything works as expected. Also, I can pass `useParams().routeName` directly to the `mapState` function and it's working. But in case of using `ownProps`, it is not working. Here is my code:

```
const CollectionPage = ({collection}) => {
  let params = useParams();
  let collectionPath = params.routeName;

  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(ownProps.collectionPath)(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage);
```

With this code, the return will be undefined, but when I hard code the value, like the code below, it’s working:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(''Some Hard Coded Value'')(state)
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960443/switch-route-doesnt-work-on-click-until-refresh-page-manually
You need to wrap your components in an HOC and pass the params manually through props, if you don't wanna update your redux API to `useSelector` `useDispatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preferred

The preferred method would be to use the React hooks directly in the component. Instead of using the `connect` [Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOC), use the `useSelector` hook to select/access the `collection` state. Refactor the `selectCollection` selector to return the state and do the filtering in the UI.

Example:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const CollectionPage = () => {
  const { routeName } = useParams();
  const collection = useSelector(state => {
    const collection = selectCollection(state);
    // Logic to return collection filtered by routeName, etc...
    return <UI value here>
  });

  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Alternative/Legacy

If you have the need to access path parameters in any `mapStateToProps` function, and if you are using a lot of other code, for example, then you'll need to create another HOC to access the path parameters and have them injected as props so they are available in the `mapStateToProps` function.

Example:

```
import { useParams, /* Other hooks */ } from "react-router-dom";

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // Other hooks, useLocation, useNavigate, etc..
  return <Component {...props} {...{ params, /* other injected props */ }} />;
};

export default withRouter;
```

...

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import withRouter from '../path/to/withRouter';

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, { params: { routeName } = {} }) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(routeName)(state),
});

export default compose(
  withRouter,              // <-- injects a params prop
  connect(mapStateToProps) // <-- props.params accessible
)(BlogDetailsPage);
```

Comment: thanks but the easier solution that i figured out is to pass useLocation() from a higher level component to this component and worked properly